Spin of an electron tunneling from a Majorana bound state to a normal metal electrode
I am reading about Majorana bound states, and don’t understand when electrons can be modelled as spinless and when as spinfull. I understand that in a semiconducting nanowire proximized to an s-wave superconductor and in a magnetic field, electrons have the same spin, but I am interested how to describe electrons when they tunnel to a nearby metallic electrode.
When describing tunneling between a topological superconductor and a quantum dot, the tunnel Hamiltonian is usually expressed with the spin index sigma (e.g. PRB 84, 140501R, eq. (2))

On the other hand, when tunneling is from the topological superconductor to a metal electrode (e.g. PRB 92, 165428, eq. (28)), electrons are assumed spinless, and sigma is suppressed (k is wave vector in a metallic electrode):

Would it be correct to model tunneling to a metallic electrode by including the spin index as follows?

The tunnel matric element lambda could be assumed to be given as introduced for a quantum dot in the above paper (PRB 84, 140501R). Or this would not be correct?

It is advisable to write equations here via MathJax (link to tutorial)

The OP misread the reference PRB 92, 165428; though I'd say it is some terrible notation.
Directly under both equations (2) and (28), it is stated that $k$ stands for all quantum numbers of the electron.  Spin is included.

In equation (6), k is wave vector (no spin included), isn’t it?
